# What are all of the cheat codes?

Tags: cheats, doom, doom-2

I've heard that there are a variety of cheat codes in both DOOM and DOOM 2, to allow things like all weapons, all keycards, walking through walls (no clipping) etc.

What are all of the cheat codes in DOOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more cheats, these are all:

- `IDFA` – Get all weapons, ammo, and mega armor with this cheat code
- `IDKFA` – Get all weapons, ammo, mega armor, and all keys with this cheat code
- `IDBEHOLDS` – Spawn a Berserk powerup with this cheat code
- `IDBEHOLDI` – Spawn an Invisibility powerup with this cheat code
- `IDBEHOLDV` – Spawn an Invulnerability powerup with this cheat code
- `IDBEHOLDL` – Spawn Light Amp Goggles with this cheat code
- `IDBEHOLDR` – Spawn a Radiation Suit with this cheat code
- `IDBEHOLDA` – Show computer area map with this cheat code
- `IDDT` – Show the entire map (must be in automap mode; enter twice to reveal all items, monsters, etc) with this cheat code
- `IDMUSxx` – Choose a BGM track (replace xx with a number 01-32) with this cheat code
- `IDDQD` – Enable God Mode with this cheat code
- `FHSHH` – Enemies ignore you until you attack with this cheat code
- `IDCLIP` – Enable no clipping mode (walk through objects) with this cheat code
- `IDCHOPPERS` – Replace your fists with chainsaws with this cheat code
- `IDMYPOS` – Show your position in code with this cheat code
- `IDCLEVxx` – Warp to the specified level (replace xx with a number 01-30) with this cheat code
- `IDCLEV31` – Unlock the first secret level with this cheat code
- `IDCLEV32` – Unlock the second secret level with this cheat code

Comment: IDCLEV31 and IDCLEV32 are for Doom 2, right?

Answer (score 4):

Below are the cheat codes for DOOM (all versions) and DOOM 2

```
Godmode                    IDDQD
All weapons + key cards    IDKFA
All weapons, no key cards  IDFA
No clipping                IDSPISPOPD (DOOM 1/Ultimate DOOM only)
No clipping (DOOM2)        IDCLIP
Show all map               IDDT
Warp to Level XX           IDCLEVxx   
     (In DOOM 1, this is (E)pisode,(M)ission ie 18 for episode 1 mission 8)
```

Use these codes to get specific items:

```
Give me a chainsaw!        IDCHOPPERS
Give item X                IDBEHOLDx  (Where x = item code)
Give beserker              IDBEHOLDS
Give invisibility          IDBEHOLDI
Give invulnerability       IDBEHOLDV
Give computer map          IDBEHOLDA
Give radiation suit        IDBEHOLDR
Give light amp goggles     IDBEHOLDL
```

Most of the cheat codes between DOOM and DOOM 2 are the same, the only real difference is for the no clip code which is `IDSPISPOPD` in DOOM and `IDCLIP` in DOOM 2 and Final DOOM.

Comment: Moar: [link](http://chemax.ru/cheat/index2.php?srch=doom)